# Checking biggest heigh from dynamic generated divs

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a structure of divs that are generated based on php code. Each row has 3 divs. It is generated like this:

Defining columns:

```
<?php
    $numOfCols = 3;
    $rowCount = 0;
    $bootstrapColWidth = 12 / $numOfCols;
?>
```

First row, starting the loop and defining width:

```
<div class="row">

   @foreach($datas as $data)
   <div class="col-md-<?php echo $bootstrapColWidth; ?>">
```

Then there's a bunch of content.

Then, in the end, each loop adds one to rowcount, and checks if the row has ended, so we can add a new one:

```
<?php
    $rowCount++;
    if($rowCount % $numOfCols == 0) echo '</div><div class="row">';
?>
            @endforeach
```

Now, it all works great, the problem is that as I add different amounts of content on each div, the heights become different and ends up becoming quite ugly.

What I'm trying to do: I'm trying to check in each row which div has the biggest height, so I can apply the same height to the other two.

-I've thought of adding a id to each div that increments, problem is I don't know how many divs there will be, so I can't prepare for each outcome.

-I've tried selecting each row with $('row div'), problem is then all divs will become the same size as the biggest of all. And I want to check by row.

Sorry for the long question, and thanks for any input!

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If yes, what version are you using?

Comment: Use flexbox, it does this automatically with no need for js

Comment: Yes, I'm using Bootstrap 4.0

Comment: As for flexbox, I didn't thought about it! Thanks for the tip, might just do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has [flexbox classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) that allow you to do this with just css. Take a look at this example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#align-self

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="align-self-stretch mr-3" style="background-color:lightblue">Aligned flex item</div>
    <div class="align-self-stretch mr-3" style="background-color:lightblue">Aligned flex item<br />With<br />More<br />Lines</div>
    <div class="align-self-stretch" style="background-color:lightblue">Aligned flex item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think flex-box is your solution : all  into flex container will have the same height.

```
<div style="display:flex">
   <div>
      ... some content
   </div>
   <div>
      ... some content
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.row-eq-height](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/) in Bootstrap 4